# Can we use "there is" for plural nouns?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number, contractions

Is the following correct:

> There's a sofa, two armchairs, a TV and a big cage for our parrots.

Or should we change it to:

> There's a sofa, there are two armchairs, there's a TV and a big cage
>   for our parrots.

Comment: *There's* is different from *there is*.

Comment: @snailplane how?

Comment: @MaulikV Educated speakers of standard English say *There's two reasons* but not *\*There is two reasons*, always *There are two reasons*.  Existential *there's* is becoming an invariant form in informal English, used by millions of speakers who would never use *there is* the same way, so we can no longer treat the two as the same thing.

Comment: @snailplane But here the op has not specified 'spoken English' and I'm quite sure in writing they both are same..aren't they?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["There IS/ARE rice, meat and potatoes on my plate"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68219/there-is-are-rice-meat-and-potatoes-on-my-plate)

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the reason we use "there's" with plurals is because it is difficult to pronounce "there're".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> There's a sofa, two armchairs, a TV and a big cage for our parrots.

This is correct.

*There's* is a contraction and can mean *there is*, *there has* or *there are*. In this case, it stands for *there are*. [As Snailplane mentions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns/31268?noredirect=1#comment57865_31241), the *there are* case has become standard in modern informal English, despite the fact that *apostrophe-s* isn't a sensible contraction for *are*. It's inappropriate in formal English to use *there's* to mean *there are*, but the same applies to all contractions as a general rule, because contractions are informal.

Why has this happened? Because *there's* is so ubiquitous and easy to say that this is now how a broad swath of native English speakers naturally talk. And we write the way we talk, so the new meaning of *there's* is valid in written English as well. Most dictionaries and other English references have not caught up with the new usage, so you won't find an entry in them explaining the *there are* case. Such materials are (in the case of English) by definition reactive; they don't dictate rules and meanings, they document them, and that takes time and effort.

What happens when we un-contract *there's*? Let's set aside the *there has* case, since it's not relevant to the question.

Normally, we conjugate the verb based on the subject. But, *there* is a dummy subject and can be either singular or plural, so for *there is X*, we must examine *X* to determine the plurality of *is*, as if it were the subject of the sentence. If *X* is a lone noun, the decision is easy. Use *is* for singular nouns and *are* for plural ones.

With lists, we decide how to conjugate based on the list's construction. For a conjunctive list (formed with *and*), then the correct conjugation is *are*. For a disjunctive list (formed with *or*), then the verb is pluralized based on the adjacent list item. For example, *there are two small ones or one big one* and *there is one big one or two small ones*. Aside from the exception in the case of *or* groups, whether the items are plural doesn't matter. A list of singular nouns grouped with *and* always calls for a plural verb.

These are the standard rules for plural conjugation, and they're unaffected by the new wrinkle in the meaning of *there's*. *There are X [singular] or Y*, *there are [singular noun]*, *there is A and B*, and *there is [plural noun]* are all ungrammatical.

So, for our example, removing the *apostrophe-s* yields this:

> There are a sofa, two armchairs, a TV and a big cage for our parrots.

Let's examine the proffered amended version.

> There's a sofa, there are two armchairs, there's a TV and a big cage for our parrots.

Breaking up the statement into a list of the form *there's X, there's Y, and there's Z* is valid, though more verbose. But what about each independent clause?

- *There's a sofa* - Correct.
- *there are two armchairs* - Correct.
- *there's a TV and a big cage for our parrots* - Correct. But, this is the same usage of *there's* as in the original; it stands for *there are*, because the two items are grouped together with *and*.

This version is correct, if a little bit awkward sounding, but it still uses *there's* in the same way as the original. Which is, of course, also correct.

Comment: Reminds me of "Here's your keys.".

Comment: An excellent example of exactly the same phenomenon. The un-contracted version is *here are your keys*.

Comment: Just to make sure: is it correct to say "There are a book and a pen on the desk."?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Since you're mentioning the "there has" case, how about "there have"? E.g. "There's been several occasions..."? Would that be weird than the "there are" case or is that just as common in informal English?

Comment: I was taught that "there is (singular)" should be used if the immediate adjacent word is singular, such as "There is sofa, two armchairs, a TV and a big cage for our parrots."

Answer (score 4):

A general rule says that a plural verb is used with two or more subjects connected by commas or a conjunction 'and'.

[GrammarBook](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) gives an example:

> A car and a bike are my means of transportation.

However, to avoid *the awkwardness* of the sentence, we'll change the order of those things.

> There **are** two armchairs, a sofa, a TV and a big cage for our parrots.

No need to repeat the location *there* there!

However, using *is* is not incorrect as well! For example, it's okay to say, *"There is a table and four chairs."* [A senior member on WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=699505) gives further explanation to this -

> You can use either. Number is usually clear in English sentences, but there are many that are unclear, and if you survey *English speakers* you will often find **a 50-50 (or otherwise) division** between those who choose singular and those who choose plural.

Comment: Please add an example to illustrate what you mean by this: *using is is not incorrect as well!* I'm having trouble getting the correct meaning out of it.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName it means using singular is also okay. And the reference is given there in the paragraph. As on the WordReference site.

Comment: Better to put the example in your answer than require people to go elsewhere to understand what you mean.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName you did not get me. The 'quoted text' *talks* about it. You don't need to go to that site. Anyway, including an example.

Comment: Absolutely right, I didn't get you or the meaning of the quote. Thanks for adding an example :). But I'm afraid it's not correct to say *there is a table and four chairs*; it should be *are*.

Comment: In your linked statement by 'A senior member on WordReference', the actual usage is neatly sidestepped, and no supporting evidence is given. I'd say that _There's_ followed by a coordinated noun phrase is idiomatic, whereas _There is_ followed by a coordinated noun phrase is far lower on the acceptability scale.

Comment: *There* is not a "location" in such a sentence any more than *it* is a "thing" in **it's raining*. It has its own grammatical role of indicating existence quite separate to it's role as indicating a location distant from the speaker.

Answer (score -3):

Because you're listing things you'd use the top one.

'There's' and 'there is' are the same thing. So the top sentence (fully) would be:

There is a sofa, two armchairs, a TV and a big cage for our parrots.

Hope this helps :)