# Which preposition is better to use in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

In [my first question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68219/3281) I used preposition "in" ("There is meat, rice and tomatoes in the plate"), but I was said, that it should be "on".

But if the plate is not flat, but deep, like a pot then you can pour soup ***in*** it, or put rice, meat etc.

Why does it have to be "on", not "in"?

Comment: A plate is never deep; it's flat or shallow. So you have to use "on".  It could be called a pot or bowl which may be followed by in.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - markdown does not work in the title, except for `--` creating em dashes.

Comment: @user24318 "this sentence" in a title is less helpful than explaining the problem precisely. When you ask a question it says _What is your English language learning question? Be specific._ I've edited the title to make it specific.

Comment: Guys please don't start an edit war. The title is as descriptive as it can be now. See http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2630/.

Answer (score 5):

Plates are by definition mostly flat.  Things can't be in them, only on them, because they don't have an inside.

[image: Rice on a plate]

If the plate is deep like a pot then it's not a plate, it's a bowl.  (Or a deep plate, but most people who don't work in crockery marketing would call a deep plate a bowl.)  You can put things in a bowl because they have an inside.

[image: Rice in a bowl]
[image: Rice in a different bowl]

Comment: And what can you say about this http://bit.ly/1KTo5mt?

Comment: Well done for finding the one bizarre exception to this rule.  That's a soup plate.  You can put soup in a soup plate, obviously.  "There is meat, rice and tomatoes in the soup plate" is OK, although people will wonder why you're serving something other than soup in a soup plate, or if you put those things in your soup.  If you're not serving soup, it's better to just call it a bowl.