# Has to vs have to with a pair of words

Tags: conjunctions, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

Which of the following is correct?

- > There **has** to be rules and regulations.
- > There **have** to be rules and regulations.

Comment: This question is not an easy one to answer. Both of them are correct and I think it depends on how you see "rules and regulations". If you consider it as a single concept, you can use "has", however, if you think of it as multiple items, you should use "have". [Related, “There IS/ARE rice, meat and potatoes on my plate”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68219/there-is-are-rice-meat-and-potatoes-on-my-plate).

Answer (score -1):

You will hear both, but technically "there **have** to be rules" is correct.

If you are confused when trying to make this point, you can also say "must", which sounds a bit formal but nobody can argue with it.

Comment: Or "should"....

Comment: @ kelario Thanks. I agree that "there have ..." would be technically correct here. But it sounds really odd !