# There is/are two times as much water

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which is correct:

> In this glass, there *is* two times as much water as in that glass.

or

> In this glass, there *are* two times as much water as in that glass.

**Note**: I know `water` is uncountable, but why do we say:

> There are two liters of water.

`Liter` and `time` are both countable nouns.

Comment: *Is.* And I would say "as *in* that glass" rather than "as that glass". Or rephrase to "This glass contains twice as much water as that glass."

Comment: @nnnnnn: _And I would say "as in that glass"_ Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, *times* is a plural noun in your sentence. And *two times* indicates *two* of this same noun. You can't use an adverb in the blank below:

> There is/are two _____ as much/many in this glass as in the other one.

This is verified by the *Oxford English Dictionary*:

> *time* (noun)
>
> 19. *In plural* Preceded by a number
>
> a. Expressing comparison:
>
> followed by an adjective or adverb in the comparative degree (e.g. *ten times bigger, ten times more slowly, ten times less*), or by *as* or (now rare) *so* with an adverb of quantity (e.g. *ten times as (or so) many (as)*, *ten times as (or so) much (as))*.

Notice we can say either

> two times as much ______ as

or

> two times as many ______ as

depending upon whether the noun in the blank is a mass noun or count noun. We use *much* with mass nouns and *many* with count nouns.

It is precisely because *water* here is being used as a mass noun that we use *is*:

> In this glass, there *is* two times as much water as in that glass.

Take  away the comparison terms  and you are left with

> In this glass there *is* water.

Now if we are comparing a count noun, we can  use *are*:

> In this glass there are two times as many ice cubes as in that glass.

And this is an expanded version of

> In this glass there are ice cubes.

So far, so good. But now comes a big caveat. Many native speakers will use *there's* in this case also, either because they are considering the ice cubes as a single set or because *there's* is a frozen form that is used by native speakers even if the following noun is plural.

> In this glass *there's* two times as many ice cubes as in that glass.

Many native speakers will even use *there's* for the reduced sentence

> In this glass there's ice cubes.

Some native speakers will find that clumsy, terrible sounding and downright ungrammatical. But the point remains that *there's* is used by native speakers to refer to more than one of something. See [Can we use "there is" for plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns) (especially the accepted answer).

So, for the above reason, you can say either

> There are two liters of water.

or

> There's two liters of water.

But you probably should use *are* in writing and formal spoken English.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at this definition of [water](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/water), you will see a small **[U]** after the word: this indicates that it is [uncountable](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/countable-uncountable-nouns-1). Other examples of uncountable words are sugar and peace.

We use the singular form of the verb with uncountable nouns.

Compare that with the following sentence using cherry, which is countable:

> In this glass, there **are** two times as **many** cherries as in that glass.

Note that we also have to change **much** to **many**: we use **much** for uncountables and **many** for uncountables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why do we say: There _are_ two liters of water.? `Liter` and `time` are both countable.

Comment: Water is uncountable, so when we want to measure it we need to use a unit of measurement (litres) and then we can count the units.  The noun in this sentence is **water**. **times** is not a noun, it's a predeterminer/adverb. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/times. An example of a countable version of **time** would be "the opening times **are** available on our web site".

Comment: _times is not a noun, it's a predeterminer/adverb._ Cambridge seems to be the only advanced learner's dictionary that doesn't consider it as a noun: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/times?q=times), [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/time), [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/time_1), [Collins COBUILD Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/time).

Comment: Interesting. If you replace **two times** with **twice**, the structure and meaning are the same. **twice** is an adverb or adverb/predeterminer in all of the dictionaries that you referenced.

Comment: Yes, `two times` / `twice` is an adverb, but not `times` itself.

Comment: Opinions vary. Anyway, you are using **two times**, so it's an adverb.