# There {is/are} a car and a bicycle in the yard

Tags: conjunctions, subject-verb-agreement, formal-language

Which of these sentences is correct? and why?

> There *is* a car and a bicycle in the yard.
>
> There *are* a car and a bicycle in the yard.

Which of these should be used in an academic essay?

Comment: How many objects are in the yard? The answer will help you to decide whether to use the singular or plural form of the verb.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: I know it is silly by I think the first one is OK too! :D So I was wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it is correct to use a singular verb form with a plural subject? Could you say: "_You and I is in the yard"_ ?

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Don't know! :) OK thanks. I got my answer. Shall I remove the question?

Comment: You could also wait for an answer... it's your call.

Comment: However "correct" using "are" might be... native speakers say "is" in this sentence all the time.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: I think my confusion is because that some times we use "and" to prevent from repeating a verb. So my mind translate this as "There is a car and there is a bicycle in the yard".

Comment: @Catija: What should I write in an academic essay? Would you please write an answer?

Comment: As @Catija (+1) says, you will often hear native speakers use _there's_ or _there is_ in conversation where the plural is "correct." People don't speak with a grammar book in mind! In formal writing, though, you should always use the correct form.

Comment: See Esoteric Screen Name's excellent answer **[here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31241/37009)** (I think he takes it too far, but there's good guidance in it...)

Comment: Related.https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not

Answer (score 3):

The correct usage here is "are", as "there" is not the subject; rather, this is known as "[expletive construction](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/oddness-when-you-start-a-sentence-with-there-is)", and the subject of the sentence is "a car and a bicycle". Check out my link for a full explanation.

In common speech, however, American native speakers will frequently say "is" for exactly the reason you mention in your comment above; we translate it internally as "There is a car and there is a bicycle in the yard". In fact, I can't shake the feeling that using "are" *sounds weird* when I hear it, no matter how I rationalize it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not just frequently. It actually sounds quite strange with "are," and it seems perhaps the language has moved on from this prescription.