# 'How is your mom and dad?'or 'How are your mom and dad?'

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

1. How is your mom and dad?
2. How are your mom and dad?

I've heard  people saying "How's your parents?" or "how's your mom and dad?" Plural subject with singular verb. I am confused.

Comment: There's several expressions in which ***are*** informally gets abbreviated to ***'s***. So you're relatively unlikely to hear "how is your Mom and Dad" but much more likely to hear "how's your Mom and Dad?"

Comment: I'd say this is nearly the same question as covered on ELU and  at [Can we use 'there is' for plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns). "There's", unlike "There is",  is usually regarded as quite acceptable with a plural / coordinate complement. And "How's", conversationally, is doubtless becoming as acceptable.

Comment: Normally the singular one would be pronounced _How's_. The auxiliary _is_ tends to be contracted wherever possible. If that's done, it doesn't follow number agreement. Especially with fixed expressions like _How's your family?_