# "There is some" or "There are some"- which is correct?

Tags: american-english, verb-agreement

I was at school and my teacher said

> There's some in there.

Was that phrase correct? Is it "*there is some in there*" or "*there are some in there*"?

Comment: "There is some X" is fine when X is an uncountable noun, for example *water.* "There are some  Xes" is for when X is a plural noun like *horses.* However, in speech and also nowadays in reputable newspapers, for example, you can have "There's some Xes ..." Note, however, that you need the contraction "There's", you cannot use two words. "**There is** some Xes" is ungrammatical!

Comment: Initial _There's_ is OK before anything. When it's at the beginning of the sentence, it's just a dummy, with no meaning or plural, and it's reified into one word before anything plural can happen in the sentence. By the time the real subject comes along, plural or not, the listener will've forgotten how the sentence started. Since it didn't start with anything meaningful except the dummy existential. Incidentally, _there is_ always gets contracted to _there's_ in speech. Not contracting is unusual and draws attention.

Answer (score 13):

Both are correct. *Some* can replace plural countable nouns (verb in the plural) or mass nouns (verb in the singular).

> There is some ***coffee*** in that cupboard. There's some in there. *(uncountable noun)*

> A: Do you have any ***pencils***? 
> B: Yes, there are some in that drawer. There are some in there. *(countable noun, plural)*

Edit: As for the use of ***there's*** (careful, not ***there is***) followed by a plural noun, it is informal:

> ***In speaking*** and ***in some informal writing***, we use ***there’s*** even *when it refers to more than one*. *This use could be considered incorrect in formal writing or in an examination*:
>
> - ***There’s three*** other people who are still to come.
> - ***There’s lots*** of cars in the car park. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/there-is-there-s-and-there-are))

Comment: +1, and I'll just add that this also applies to other indefinite pronouns, such as "all", "none" (though some people treat that one differently), and "most".

Comment: Can you address the arguable correctness of using "There's X" when X is countable? For instance, how wrong is "Yes, **there's** some pencils in that drawer."

Comment: @gotube I think the accepted answer of this question on ELL, [Can we use "there is" for plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns/31268?noredirect=1#comment57865_31241) already does that. But ok, I guess I should oblige a good mod :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

There **is some**...(Some refers to an uncountable noun)

There **are some**... (Some refers to a plural noun)

**Some** is a determiner and a pronoun.

We can use **some** before a **plural noun**/countable noun or a **mass noun**/uncountable noun. **Some** used before/with an uncountable noun takes a singular verb. Some used before/with a plural noun takes a plural verb.

There **is** some cake in the kitchen. There **are** some flowers in the kitchen.

countable - some cars, some tourists,

uncountable- some advice, some help

We can use **some** on its own.

There were some old books in the room. **Some** were damaged but **some** were all right.

I have made tea. Would you like **some**?

If you need any money, I’ll lend you **some**.

**Some** means part of a quantity. We can use **some** with 'of'

**Some of** my books **are** new. (a part but not all)

**Some of** the money **is** mine.

Can I have **some of** the cake?

**All** and **most** can also be used before a plural noun or an uncountable noun.

all children, all flowers, most tourists, most people, all information, most tap water, most research