# Are both verb forms acceptable? "There is/are marks all over it."

Tags: grammar, verbs, singular-vs-plural, british-english

a) There are marks all over it.
b) There is marks all over it.

[“Is” vs. “Are”—Correct Usage](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/is-vs-are/)

Can *is* be switched with are here or it is ungrammatical to do so?

I may be inclined to say in speech: there is marks all over this floor, for instance.

It sort of fits unlike more obvious examples: These are my books. This is our house.

Comment: Marks is a plural noun, so in standard English, you need to use a plural verb ('there **are** marks') but in casual speech some native speakers ignore this and use a singular verb ('there is marks', or very often, 'there's marks'). When I was at school, the teachers tried to stop children doing that. It is not standard English, and could be considered incorrect in formal writing or in an examination.

Comment: We often use (almost always *contracted*) ***There's*** when object is obviously plural, as in [*There's a sofa, two armchairs, a TV and a big cage for our parrots.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns). Here are written instances of [*There's marks on ...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22There%27s+marks+on%22), but you won't find that format *uncontracted*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use "there is" for plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns)

Comment: Did you read the article you linked? "When choosing between *there is* and *there are*, you have to look at what comes after the phrase." Why are you confused?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is about what is grammatically "correct," I feel like the linked Grammarly article is clear:

> When choosing between *there is* and *there are*, you have to look at what comes after the phrase:
> Example: ***There is a cat** on the porch*
> In the sentence above, *cat* is the subject, and since it is singular, it requires *there is*.
> Example: ***There are many opportunities** to learn at this company.*
> In the sentence above, *opportunities* is the subject, and since it is plural, it requires *there are*.

In your example sentence, *marks* is plural. You should use *there are*.

But since this is so clear, the rest of your question seems to be: Don't we hear people talk this way? Don't we hear "there is" even with plural subjects? Yes. This is where "grammatically correct" and "commonly used" aren't always the same thing. I could imagine someone saying "There is marks all over this floor." It would be a very informal way of speaking, and perhaps even associated with certain regions or groups of people. Personally I wouldn't say it; it wouldn't feel natural for me, not belonging to those groups. It would certainly feel out of place in writing (aside from the most informal writing like text messages). And I wouldn't advise an English learner to try it, especially since saying "There *are* marks all over this floor" would not sound unnatural or unwelcome in most contexts. (Unlike some other "grammar rules" that are so often broken that it might sound odd to stick to the "right" way.)

If the verb and subject have a few more words between them, the mismatch becomes less obvious. For instance, "There's a lot of people here today" doesn't sound quite so colloquial, and I say things like that myself often enough.

Comment: I think many people know that they should say, contractedly, _there're_, but find the repeated 'r' sounds awkward.

Comment: Nobody says *"**There is** marks all over this floor."* But millions of people see nothing wrong with contracted *"**There's** marks all over this floor"* in spoken contexts. It makes no sense to say they *should* use the ugly / awkward contraction ***There're..***

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, the groups that I could imagine saying it would be likely to contract. But I could imagine it uncontracted if they're particularly irate about it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I did know someone who said _there're_. It did sound a bit odd. I myself will say 'there are'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: There're too many ways to slip up in speech with that one - especially if you've had a drop of the hard stuff! :)

Comment: But imho nobody - *but **nobody*** - says *"There are a knife and fork on the table"* when you ask for the cutlery to go with your laptop TV dinner! And seriously, who would mess about with the contracted plural there?