# "There is" or "there are" with compound subjects that have a mix of plural and singular elements

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, compound-subjects, proximity-agreement

1. There is a cat, a dog, and an elephant in the room.
2. There are two cats, a dog, and an elephant in the room.
3. There is a cat, two dogs, and an elephant in the room.

In the first sentence, all of these animals are acting as a single unit, thus the subject is singular. But I'm not sure about the 2 and 3. Why plural subject for 2 and the opposite for 3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There's vs There are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are) Also [Can we use "there is" for plural nouns?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/can-we-use-there-is-for-plural-nouns) and others

Comment: What makes you think they're "a single unit" in the first example?

Answer (score 2):

> *There is a cat, a dog, and an elephant in the room.*
>
> *There are two cats, a dog, and an elephant in the room.*
>
> *There is a cat, two dogs, and an elephant in the room.*

In all these examples, the subject is "there", not the various animals.

The verb-form is usually determined by the concept of proximity: the verb agrees with the nearest coordinate.

It's not actually a rule as such, but a useful guide in some cases.

On that understanding, they are all OK.

Comment: My gut feel was we'd normally itemize the *single* item first, if the other was plural, but checking out [all 4 permutations of 1 or 2 cats and 1 or 2 dogs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+cats+and+a+dog%2Ca+dog+and+two+cats%2Ctwo+dogs+and+a+cat%2Ca+cat+and+two+dogs&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) it seems we consistently tend to specify the plural item first with *those*. Perhaps I was misled by thinking of things like *a mother and [her] two children, a table and chairs, a coach and horses, fish and chips...*

Comment: "There" is the *subject*? Is it not simply an inversion of "a cat is there"?

Comment: @AndyBonner "There" must be the subject for several reasons: (1) it occupies the basic subject position before the verb phrase. (2) In subject-aux inversions it occurs after the auxiliary, as in "Was there a cat ...". [3] It occurs as subject in interrogative tags, cf. "There was a cat etc, wasn't there?".

Answer (score 0):

All sentences are correct

1. There is a cat, a dog, and an elephant in the room.
2. There are two cats, a dog, and an elephant in the room.
3. There is a cat, two dogs, and an elephant in the room.

However It is uncommon to have an elephant in a room, so these sentences might feel unusual or unrealistic in terms of content.

**The reason why number 3 is written with "is" instead of "are"** is because In English, when using "there is" or "there are" constructions, we typically match the verb tense with the noun that follows, rather than the nouns that come after it. Therefore, because "cat" is the first noun in the series, we use the singular verb "is." The subsequent nouns "two dogs" and "an elephant" do not affect the verb tense. So, the correct form of the sentence is: "There is a cat, two dogs, and an elephant in the room."